# Error calling Microsoft Graph privilegedOperationEvents with application permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I already call several graph endpoints using application permissions. Now I would also like to call the privilegedOperationEvents using application permissions.

Requesting https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedOperationEvents, I get this error:

```
{ 
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "37a18529-5184-4ad6-93ad-b6d4bf746a90",
            "date": "2018-11-23T09:35:04"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the cause if. I suspect it might be that this endpoint is not supported with application permissions, but that's not in the error nor can I find it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application permission is not support to call the api, refer to this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/privilegedoperationevent_list).

[image]

Comment: To bad. Thank your for replying.